# How to Update a field in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to Update only name field if only name is sent from frontend, update only image if only image is sent  from frontend, update both if name  & image is sent from frontend In Django

```
data =request.data

if data['name'] and data['image']:            
   category= Category.objects.get(id=data['id'])
   category.name=data['name']
   category.image=data['image']
   category.save()

elif data['name']:            
   category= Category.objects.get(id=data['id'])
   category.name=data['name']
   category.save()

else:            
   category= Category.objects.get(id=data['id'])
   category.image=data['image']
   category.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a dictionary that only contains the key-value pairs to update and then use [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) to update the corresponding `Category` record:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(id=data['id'])
updates = {}

if 'name' in data:
    updates['name'] = data['name']
if 'image' in data:
    updates['image'] = data['image']

if updates:
    categories.update(**updates)
```